# MVC Folder Structure for Project with Multiple Themes/Skin

Tags: php, model-view-controller, templates, themes

I'm working on a project that has multiple theme/skin and is extensible via plugins.

As it stands right now my folder is structured as such.

```
vc/
  controller/
          home/
  view/
      classic/
           home/
      spring/
           home/
  plugin/
     feedReader/
             view/
             locale/
 template/
    header.html
    footer.html
```

Some things about this structure:

`controller` contains my controllers. 
`view` contains controller views; because the project uses multiple themes, views are segmented into a theme -- `classic` and `spring` -- folder.  `plugin` contains plugins with it's associated `view` and `locale` (language) data. `template` contains templates that may be included in my rendered view.

I'm  using a template engine so with the output of each view I may include the template of a header and footer in addition to a left or right column containing one or more plugin. These templates **may** vary based on the theme, so there's a need to separate them based on theme.

My question is what might one recommend in terms of ideal folder structure. Right now things are spread across several directories, so import and export of views plus keeping track on files during editing can become tedious.